# How to restrict shipping address per country and allow any billing address?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, multistore, billing

I'm using a multi-website Magento configuration with per country specific prices and rules.

Magento allows to specify countries allocated to each store in admin area which is solves half of the problem, however our business model allows customer to use any billing address and restrict shipping destination from each store individually.

For example we have a warehouse in US which ships items withing USA and UK warehouse which ships items internationally except USA.

Currently Magento checkout ([OneStepCheckot](http://www.onestepcheckout.com/)) presume, that if billing address is set, shipping address is optional or billing address can be used instead, this approach can be accurate for majority but in our case it's supposed to be opposite. What we care about is a destination, as final price might vary due to many factors like customs, local authority tax etc.

Can some one suggest how it can be achieved?

Comment: What about the BILLING address (you answered for Ship To)... how can we enable International countries for Billing address?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156031)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156031)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Magento has already solved this by limiting shipping methods by destination country:

**System > Config > Shipping Methods > [Method]**

[image]

All that would be needed is some messaging on checkout in the shipping destination entry and shipping method selection areas which would notify which countries you ship to.

Comment: How can i configure, selected items not for specific countries (not all items only few items).

Comment: @Gem you can Ctrl+Click on the list.

Comment: @LiamMitchell Really appreciate your response, thank you.