# Limit billing countries while leaving all shipping countries

Tags: magento-1.9, billing-address

I have 3 Magento sites (not multiSite), 1.7.0.2, 1.8.1, and 1.9.1.

I followed the instructions here > [Allow multiple countries for billing but restrict for shipping](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/allow-multiple-countries-for-billing-but-restrict-for-shipping)

I can't seem to limit the billing countries as none of these have  `\app\design\frontend\default\Your_Theme\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml`

I am using default package as well as a default theme. Is there another method?

I want to only accept USA and CA billing addresses, but accept other countries "ship to's".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow multiple countries for billing but restrict for shipping](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/allow-multiple-countries-for-billing-but-restrict-for-shipping)

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured in the Admin Panel by going to `System->Configuration Page`

1. Click on **Shipping Methods** tab under **Sales**
2. Based on your allowed/configured Shipping methods, limit the countries.
3. Click on **Save Config**
4. Click on **Payment Methods** tab under **Sales**
5. Based on the payment method, **Payment from Specific Countries** can limit the list of countries allowed to bill.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am doing, but I don't want the billing countries to show up to even get to the payment methods.

Comment: @docwho Magento 1.x out-of-the-box doesn't provide the ability to remove the entire payment options tab based on countries.